# Ввод данных с клавиатуры в OpenGL (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opengl

Как ввести данные во время выполнения программы в OpenGL?

У меня программа рисует график функции в окне, после того как график отобразился, мне нужно вести с клавиатуры значения: диапазон для поиска корня и точность.
Потом отобразить корень на графике

```
void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    vector <float> val_X;// здесь иксы
    vector <float> val_Y;// здесь значения F(x);
    float step = 0.001; //приращение к иксу

    draw_grid(0.3, 5.0);  //оси

    info_func(-25, 25, step, val_Y, val_X);
    draw_func(val_Y, val_X); // тут рисуется график
    glFlush();


    //диапазон поиска
    //ввожу через консоль
    int a, b;
    float eps;
    cin >> a >> b;
    cin >> eps;

    //здесь в консоле выводится найденный корень
    //и окно opengl зависает, по идеи функция show_root() должна отображать
    //на графике точку
    float root = root_search(a, b, eps);

    show_root(root);
    glFlush();

}
```

Comment: **Ввод данных никак не должен быть связан с тем, что вы используете OpenGL.** Не смешивайте разные вещи в 1 методе. Опишите нам, как вы себе представляете функционирование программы - ввод данных, отрисовка 1 кадра, снова ввод или как-то иначе?

Comment: Отрисовка 1 кадра (график функции). Ввод данных(диапазон в котором искать корень и точность). Отрисовка 2 кадра на основе этих данных ( показывает на графике найденный корень уравнения)

Comment: Если делать красиво, то можно нарисовать что то типа textbox в котором эмулировать ввод при помощи glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);

Answer (score 0):

Если вы работаете с glut библиотекой.

Вам нужно чтение из консоли вынести поза функцию рисования.

```
//Вот так можно зарегистрировать функцию роботы с клавиатурой.
glutKeyboardFunc(k2);
```

А там вызывать консоль например пробелом

Также в конце каждой отрисовки нужно вызывать

```
glutSwapBuffers(); //Вывести на экран (Переключение буферов)
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); //Очистка экрана
```

Не помню что зачинит `glFlush();` возможно что то вроде `glutSwapBuffers();`

если бы вы также добавили зависимые функции, я бы исправил код. Но их нет.